# How to do matrix-scalar multiplication in TensorFlow with batch?

Tags: python, tensorflow, matrix-multiplication

At the beginning, I will describe formula, what I am trying to compute:

[Math formula on google chat api](https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=tx&chl=L%3DI%2B%5Csum%5E%7BC%7DN_i%5E%7Bc%7DT%5E%7Bc%7B%5Cprime%7D%7DT%5E%7Bc%7D) (I can't post image directly.)

where I is identity matrix with shape (M,M), N_i is the vector (C) and T is the matrix (C*F,M), T_c are submatrices with shape (F,M).

My code for tensorflow to enumerate this look like that:

```
N_p = tf.placeholder(floatX, shape=[C], name='N_p')
I = tf.Variable(np.eye(M),dtype=tf.float32, name="I")
T = tf.Variable(np.random.rand(C*F,M),dtype=tf.float32, name="T")

L = I
for i,T_c in enumerate([T[i:i+F,:] for i in xrange(0,F*C,F)]):
    L=tf.add(L,tf.scalar_mul(N_p[i],tf.matmul(tf.transpose(T_c),T_c)))
```

This works fine, unfortunately, I need expand this into batch processing, here N_p will be:

```
N_p = tf.placeholder(floatX, shape=[None,C], name='N_p')
```

Unfortunately, I don't know hor change my tensorflow formula.
Problem is in scalar_mul.

```
L=tf.add(L,tf.scalar_mul(N_p[:,i],tf.matmul(tf.transpose(T_c),T_c)))
```

what is obvious why, but how to rewrite it?
Thanks a lot for any advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve the above in matrix form, without any loops:

```
T --> [C, F, M]
T_1 --> transpose T to --> [C, F, M]
T_2 --> transpose T to --> [C, M, F]
d --> matmul (T_1, T_2) --> [C, M, M] --> transpose --> [M, M, C]
out --> multiply (d, N) : d -> [1, M, M, C], N -> [batch, 1, 1, C]
      --> [batch, M, M, C] --> reduce_sum (axis=2) --> [batch, M, M]
      --> add I
```

The working code (matches your code for `batch=1`):

```
N_1 = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, C])
reshape_T = tf.reshape(T, [C, F, M])

# reshape to do a batch matrix multiplication (C, F, M) and (C, M, F)
T_1 = tf.transpose(reshape_T, [0, 2, 1])
T_2 = tf.transpose(reshape_T, [0, 1, 2])

d = tf.transpose(tf.matmul(T_1,T_2), [2,1,0])
out = tf.reduce_sum(d[None,...]* tf.reshape(N_1, [-1, 1, 1, C]), axis=3) + I

with tf.Session() as sess:
   sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
   print(sess.run(out, {N_1: inp}))
```